# \ref not working with achemso

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, achemso

I'm trying to write a document with the `achemso` package, but my `\ref` are not working right. `achemso` links to a package called `cleveref`, then renames `cleveref`'s `\cref` into `\ref`, so any answers for `cleveref` should work here.

Example one:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,layout=traditional]{achemso}
\usepackage{achemso} %loaded last due to clerverRef

\author{Canageek}
\title{Title}
\email{fake@email.ca}
\affiliation[University]{University, Canada}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction \label{intro}}
blah blah blah blah

\section{two}
Will this work? See~\ref{intro}.

\end{document}
```

Produces as it's body text:

> Introduction
>
> blah blah blah blah
>
> two
>
> Will this work? See Footnote ∗.

Next example, since there is mention of a error with references in section titles in the `cleveref` manual.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,layout=traditional]{achemso}
\usepackage{achemso} %loaded last due to clerverRef

\author{Canageek}
\title{Title}
\email{fake@email.ca}
\affiliation[University]{University, Canada}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
 \label{intro}
blah blah blah blah

\section{two}
Will this work? See~\ref{intro}.

\end{document}
```

This gives the same output as above.
Oddly enough neither produce anything odd that I can find in the `.log` file.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,layout=traditional,hyperref]{achemso}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{achemso} %loaded last due to clerverRef


\author{Canageek}
\title{Title}
\email{fake@email.ca}
\affiliation[University]{University, Canada}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
 \label{intro}
blah blah blah blah

\section{two}
Will this work? See~\ref{intro}.

\end{document}
```

Gives a different output: It replaces the `*` with a `??`.
The `.log` file for this one also has the message

> LaTeX Warning: cref  reference format for label type `' undefined on input line
>    17.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I made sure to update my TeX Live install this morning when I had another problem, so everything should be up to date. Oh, and yes, I've made sure to delete everything but the `test.tex` file from the folder between compiles.

Comment: Also note that achemso has been updated very recently: version v3.5j, last revised 2011/11/14. (You probably update regularly, but there might be readers of this who don't do it.)

Comment: I don't actually, unless I have a problem, but I'd happened to update the same day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to cross-reference the sections, they should have a number associated (to be used in cross-referencing) otherwise, the wrong string will be picked up to produce the cross-reference number (in your case, it will be the one created by `\affiliation` which explains why you were getting "Footnote").

`achemso` uses section numbers only where the journal uses these in print. You can use the `\SectionNumbersOn` command to force section numbering; however, if you use section numbers in a submission to a journal which does not use them, things may go a bit wrong later.

Your document could be something like this:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,layout=traditional]{achemso}
\usepackage{achemso}

\SectionNumbersOn

\author{Canageek}
\title{Title}
\email{fake@email.ca}
\affiliation[University]{University, Canada}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{intro}
blah blah blah blah

\section{two}
Will this work? See~\ref{intro}.

\end{document}
```

[image]